# Using a Proxy as an ACL

Tags: php, design-patterns, access-control

I am building an MVC application in PHP, using Zend Framework.

My model includes Domain Model and Mapper layers.  I am trying to keep the domain model in pristine condition and have managed to keep it free from persistence-related code.  Now I am trying to find a solution for ACL.

I have 'general' ACL rules that can be easily enforced in a service layer, but I also have some very fine grained rules.  The fine grained rules apply at the property level and affect whether the current user can alter a field, and if so, what the range of allowable values is.

Currently I am thinking of using the proxy pattern, and that the proxy should extend the real object (to save me having to redirect 100% of calls).  Does this sound reasonable?  Is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend your ACL class from the original class, you're not following the Proxy pattern. A Proxy controlls the access to a given subject, implementing the same interface as the subject.

Using traits in PHP, you can build a generic Decorator, which you can use for all Proxies and Decorators.

```
interface MyModel {...}

class ConcreteModel implements MyModel
{
    // Your properties and methods as usual
}

trait Decorator
{
    private $subject;

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
    }

    // You might want to implement __callStatic, __get, and __set, too
}

class AclProxy implements MyModel
{
    use Decorator;

    public function __construct(MyModel $model)
    {
        $this->subject = $model;
    }

    // Your specific overrides go here
}
```